# latest rate and sum of quantity from mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a table look like below:

```
uid    added_on                rm_id     qnty        rate

1      2017-10-23 10:48:50     5         2           30
2      2017-10-23 10:48:50     6         4           70
3      2017-10-23 10:48:50     7         5           10
4      2017-10-24 11:02:10     5         10          28
5      2017-10-24 11:02:10     6         2           75
6      2017-10-24 11:03:37     7         1           15
7      2017-10-25 11:02:10     6         5           65
8      2017-10-25 11:03:37     7         8           12
```

I need the `rm_id` , its `quantity` (that is rm_id 5 is  12(2+10) ), and its last added `rate`(latest rate can find from the latest added_on rate or from last uid for each rm_id). Any way the result should look like below:

**Result**

```
rm_id  total_qnty   rate

5      12           28
6      11           65
7      14           12
```

I tried to achieve this by using

```
SELECT `rm_id`, sum(`qnty`),`rate` FROM `stock` group by `rm_id` having max(`uid`)
```

and

```
  SELECT `rm_id`, sum(`qnty`),`rate` FROM `stock` group by `rm_id` having max(date(`added_on`))
```

But not getting the result as desired.. please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to locate the max date, and from that determine the rate, and apply that rate to the summed quantity.

```
select
    t.rm_id, t.rate, gd.sum_qty, gd.sum_qty * t.rate
from table1 t
inner join (
    select rm_id, max(added_on) max_date, sum(qnty) sum_qty
    from table1
    group by rm_id
    ) gd on t.rm_id = gd.rm_id and t.added_on = gd.max_date
```

The data model is strange, why aren't rates separated?

Answer (score 1):

`having max(uid)` translates to `having 8` for `rm_id = 7`. And MySQL treats numbers > 0 as true, so this becomes `having true`, i.e. don't limit my results in any way. The aggregated result doesn't contain the single rates anyway, so it's too late to try to get it via `HAVING`. You'd need an aggregation function for this, such as Oracle's `KEEP LAST`, but MySQL doesn't feature this.

What you want instead is to get the maximum `uid` and with its help select the related record:

```
select
  stock.rm_id,
  stockagg.sum_qnty,
  stock.rate as last_rate
from 
(
  select 
    rm_id, 
    sum(qnty) as sum_qnty, 
    max(uid) as max_uid
  from stock 
  group by rm_id
) stockagg
join stock on stock.uid = stockagg.max_uid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use subqueries:

```
SELECT `rm_id`, sum(`qnty`),
  (SELECT `rate`
   FROM `stock` s1
   WHERE `uid` = (SELECT `uid`
                  FROM `stock` s2
                  WHERE s2.`rm_id` = s1.`rm_id`
                  ORDER BY `added_on` DESC
                  LIMIT 1)
  ) AS `rate`
FROM `stock`
GROUP BY `rm_id`
```

Comment: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: Yes, I was still typing my answer. Try it now.